# How to calculate a future contracts price?

Tags: interest-rates, futures, hedging, eurodollars

I have the following question from Hull, [problem 6.17](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0ahUKEwirvZa_6d7XAhXDEbwKHVXPCIcQFghEMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffinpko.faculty.ku.edu%2Fmyssi%2Findex.php%3Fdir%3DFIN832%2FChapter%2520Problem%2520Solutions%2FHull%25209th%2520Edition%2F%26file%3DHullFund9eCh06ProblemSolutions.doc&usg=AOvVaw0R0H4SHBW8zlbAXHo2UHVI):

---

*On August 1 a portfolio manager has a bond portfolio worth $10 million. The duration of the portfolio in October will be 7.1 years. The December Treasury bond futures price is currently 91-12 and the cheapest-to-deliver bond will have a duration of 8.8 years at maturity. How should the portfolio manager immunize the portfolio against changes in interest rates over the next two months?*

---

The solution is as follows:

*The treasurer should short Treasury bond futures contract. If bond prices go down, this futures position will provide offsetting gains. The number of contracts that should be shorted is:*

$$\begin{align} Number\ of\ Contracts& =\frac{$\ 10\,000\,000}{\bbox[yellow, 5px,border:2px solid red]{$\ 91\,375}}\times\frac{7.1\ \text{years}}{8.8\ \text{years}} \newline
 & = 88.30 \ \text{contracts}\newline
\therefore Number\ of\ Contracts &\approx 88\  \text{contracts}\end{align}$$

---

*Question:*

How was the $91,375 calculated?

Comment: Please refer to page 2 of https://www.cmegroup.com/education/files/understanding-treasury-futures.pdf.

Comment: @helinGai Never seen this notation before. Thanks! $\therefore$  91-12 = 91 + 12/32 = 91.375%,  91.375% x \$1,000,000 = \$ 91,375

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question reads "*...price is currently 91-12...*" where *91-12* is  notated in futures quotes ([pg. 2 of Treasury Futures](https://www.cmegroup.com/education/files/understanding-treasury-futures.pdf)). Coupon-bearing securities are frequently quoted in percent of par to the nearest 1/32nd of 1% of par. This means that:
$$\begin{align}91\mbox{-}12 & = 91 + \frac{12}{32}\newline & = 91 + 0.375\newline & = 91.375 \newline \newline \therefore 91\mbox{-}12& =91.375\%\end{align}$$

To calculate the future contract price:
$$\begin{align}Future\ Contract\ Price& = 91.375\%\times $\ 1\,000\,000\newline &=$\ 91\,375\end{align}$$